# Jscape MFT Server Windows Service Stopping

Tags: service, server, windows-services

I run a computer that functions as a server for transferring files into and out of the company. It runs Jscape MFT server. I've recently had to migrate over to a new domain and since doing so, the Server service on the computer goes through a continuous Start / Stop process.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

What information do you need for assistance?

Comment: Are there relevant logs, perhaps logging a configuration error or failure to connect before it begins to stop?

Comment: not that i've been able to locate.

Comment: I simply ask because generally services enter a restart loop when they fail some validation/sanity check on start which causes them to shutdown again.

Comment: Yeah, i've been looking through everything that i can to find a resolution on it and i'm pulling my hair out at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you've provided enough information to get a good answer here, a specific error message or the section of config that, when changed, produces the bad behavior would go a long way in helping you debug